# Use protocol to define property of swiftui view

Tags: swiftui

I have multiple classes that I want to use with a budget picker view. They all have this budgetable protocol defined.

```
import SwiftUI

struct BudgetPickerView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var userData: UserData
    @State var budgetable: Budgetable
    ...
}
```

```
import Foundation

protocol Budgetable
{
    var budgetId: String { get set }
}
```

For example this Allocation class

```
import Foundation
import Combine

class Allocation: ObservableObject, Identifiable, Budgetable {
    let objectWillChange = ObservableObjectPublisher()

    let id: String?
    var amount: String { willSet { self.objectWillChange.send() } }
    var budgetId: String { willSet { self.objectWillChange.send() } }

    init(id: String? = nil, amount: String, budgetId: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.amount = amount.removePrefix("-")
        self.budgetId = budgetId
    }
}
```

However, when I try to pass an allocation into my budget picker view I get an error

```
NavigationLink(destination: BudgetPickerView(budgetable: allocation))...
```

> Cannot convert return expression of type 'NavigationLink>, BudgetPickerView>' to return type 'some View'
>
> Expression type 'BudgetPickerView' is ambiguous without more context

Comment: first need to pass EnvironmentObject like NavigationLink(destination: BudgetPickerView(budgetable: allocation).EnvironmentObject(UserData()))

Comment: that is already set on Scene Delegate, and it also does not remove the error when I add that

Comment: Wherever you call BudgetPickerView must have to pass EnvironmentObject as well

Comment: The same error still remains even when I do that

Comment: and why you pass as param BudgetPickerView(budgetable: allocation) your budgetable seems State in BudgetPickerView?

Comment: try to change in BudgetPickerView @State var budgetable: Budgetable to var budgetable: Budgetable

Comment: I have tried that already and it doesn't change it

Answer (score 0):

Change as bellow code

```
struct BudgetPickerView: View {
   @EnvironmentObject var userData: UserData
   var budgetable: Budgetable
   var body: some View {
   ...
   }
}
```

and

```
NavigationLink(destination: BudgetPickerView(budgetable: allocation).EnvironmentObject(UserData()))
```

Comment: this does not work, you have to add the environment object with `.environmentObject` or else you get a different error, but with that fixed I get the same error as I posted in the question.

Answer (score 0):

By SwiftUI concept you are not allowed to work with `@State` outside of View, but the following works well (having other your parts unchanged)

```
struct BudgetPickerView: View {
    @State private var budgetable: Budgetable

    init(budgetable: Budgetable) {
        _budgetable = State<Budgetable>(initialValue: budgetable)
    }

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
    }
}
struct TestBudgetPickerView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: 
               BudgetPickerView(budgetable: Allocation(amount: "10", budgetId: "1"))) 
               { Text("Item") }
        }
    }
}
```

BTW, just incase, again by design @State is intended to hold *temporary-view-state-only* data, not a model. For model is more preferable to use `ObservableObject`. In your case `Budgetable` looks like a model.

Comment: right, but you can't use ObservableObject with a protocol